# Cannot find discord bot after successfully authorizing

Tags: discord

I am new to creating a discord bot. I hope you can all give me a good solution to my problem.
I tried to create a bot for a company's server and followed a free guide. I had one problem when adding the bot to the server.
I got a message that the authorization succeeded but I cannot find the bot on the server. The guide clearly mentioned that I can find an offline bot. So I created my own discord server and tried again. OMG, it went well.

What's the problem?
Should I change the discord server setting? If yes, which option?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the server settings are done in the way that the bot does not have a permissions to be in the channel you are trying to find it in. If you have admin permissions take a look into User management in server settings if the bot did or did not join and if it did, give it some permissions so that it has an access to the channel you want to see it in.

(On the right panel you see member of the channel you are currently clicked onto not the entire server.)

Comment: thanks for your response. I cannot find the bot name in the user list.

Comment: @Christopher Hard to pinpoint the problem then, not even in Server settings>Integrations?

Comment: yup, I cannot find

Comment: @Christopher Do you have any other bots on the server? And do you have to whitelist people in some way before they can join the server?

Comment: There are other bots that my colleagues created using webhook - https://discohook.org/.

Comment: @Christopher I'd probably ask them how they added those bots, because I other than bot settings I don't see what could go wrong. I was thinking that some other bot is kicking the bot as soon as it joins, or it's something in the way you authorize your bot. Now I'd check if bot think he is still joined on the server by this `const botGuilds = await client.guilds.fetch()` If the botGuilds contains your guild, the bot is still somewhere there. I just plain cannot explain what else could be going on.